# Is it ok to use `any?` to check if an array is not empty?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is it bad to check if an array is **not** empty by using `any?` method?

```
a = [1,2,3]

a.any?
=> true

a.clear

a.any?
=> false
```

Or is it better to use `unless a.empty?` ?

Answer (score 276, accepted):

`any?` isn't the same as `not empty?` in some cases.

```
>> [nil, 1].any?
=> true
>> [nil, nil].any?
=> false
```

From the documentation:

> If the block is not given, Ruby adds
>   an implicit block of {|obj| obj} (that
>   is any? will return true if at least
>   one of the collection members is not
>   false or nil).

Comment: Is there any function opposite to `empty?` ?

Comment: @RocketR you might want to checkout `present?` method.

Comment: @dantastic `#present?` is Rails-only. In pure Ruby you'll get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'present?' for Array`.

Comment: Not exactly Rails-only, [Active Support](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) can be used without rails, just need to `require 'activesupport'`.

Answer (score 96):

#### The difference between an array evaluating its values to `true` or if its empty.

The method `empty?` comes from the Array class
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F

It's used to check if the array contains something or not. This includes things that evaluate to `false`, such as `nil` and `false`.

```
>> a = []
=> []
>> a.empty?
=> true
>> a = [nil, false]
=> [nil, false]
>> a.empty?
=> false
>> a = [nil]
=> [nil]
>> a.empty?
=> false
```

---

The method `any?` comes from the Enumerable module.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F

It's used to evaluate if "any" value in the array evaluates to `true`.
Similar methods to this are `none?`, `all?` and `one?`, where they all just check to see how many times true could be evaluated. which has nothing to do with the count of values found in a array.

case 1

```
>> a = []
=> []
>> a.any?
=> false
>> a.one?
=> false
>> a.all?
=> true
>> a.none?
=> true
```

case 2

```
>> a = [nil, true]
=> [nil, true]
>> a.any?
=> true
>> a.one?
=> true
>> a.all?
=> false
>> a.none?
=> false
```

case 3

```
>> a = [true, true]
=> [true, true]
>> a.any?
=> true
>> a.one?
=> false
>> a.all?
=> true
>> a.none?
=> false
```

Answer (score 36):

Avoid `any?` for large arrays.

- `any?` is `O(n)`
- `empty?` is `O(1)`

`any?` does not check the length but actually scans the whole array for truthy elements.

```
static VALUE
rb_ary_any_p(VALUE ary)
{
  long i, len = RARRAY_LEN(ary);
  const VALUE *ptr = RARRAY_CONST_PTR(ary);

  if (!len) return Qfalse;
  if (!rb_block_given_p()) {
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) if (RTEST(ptr[i])) return Qtrue;
  }
  else {
    for (i = 0; i < RARRAY_LEN(ary); ++i) {
        if (RTEST(rb_yield(RARRAY_AREF(ary, i)))) return Qtrue;
    }
  }
  return Qfalse;
}
```

`empty?` on the other hand checks the length of the array only.

```
static VALUE
rb_ary_empty_p(VALUE ary)
{
  if (RARRAY_LEN(ary) == 0)
    return Qtrue;
  return Qfalse;
}
```

The difference is relevant if you have "sparse" arrays that start with lots of `nil` values, like for example an array that was just created.

Comment: In this use case the difference is relevant only if you have "sparse" arrays that start with lots of `nil` values, with "normal" arrays `any?` without block returns at the first element, so the complexity is still O(1) like the `empty?` method

Answer (score 34):

Prefixing the statement with an exclamation mark will let you know whether the array is not empty. So in your case -

```
a = [1,2,3]
!a.empty?
=> true
```

Comment: Double negation? Are you serious?

Comment: He is so not not serious!

Comment: Hehe. Double negation is not ideal, just seems more readable in this specific case.

Comment: The double negative was part of the original question "Check for array not empty".  This answers the question.

Answer (score 6):

I'll suggest using `unless`and `blank` to check is empty or not.

Example :

```
unless a.blank?
  a = "Is not empty"
end
```

This will know 'a' empty or not. 
If 'a' is blank then the below code will not run.

Comment: `#blank?` is part of Rails. If they're already using Rails, `#present?` is the negation of `#blank?` anyway.

Comment: This is a question about arrays, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's bad to use `any?` at all. I use it a lot. It's clear and concise.

However if you are concerned about all `nil` values throwing it off, then you are really asking if the array has `size > 0`. In that case, this dead simple extension (NOT optimized, monkey-style) would get you close.

```
Object.class_eval do

  def size?
    respond_to?(:size) && size > 0
  end

end

> "foo".size?
 => true
> "".size?
 => false
> " ".size?
 => true
> [].size?
 => false
> [11,22].size?
 => true
> [nil].size?
 => true
```

This is fairly descriptive, logically asking "does this object have a size?". And it's concise, and it doesn't require ActiveSupport. And it's easy to build on.

Some extras to think about:

1. This is not the same as `present?` from ActiveSupport.
2. You might want a custom version for `String`, that ignores whitespace (like `present?` does).
3. You might want the name `length?` for `String` or other types where it might be more descriptive.
4. You might want it custom for `Integer` and other `Numeric` types, so that a logical zero returns `false`.