# SQLite check if a row exists

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to check if a specific ID exists in a table named "Products" in my sqlite database.

```
def existsCheck( db, id )
    temp = db.execute( "select exists(
        select 1
        from Products
        where promoID = ?
    ) ", [id] )
end
```

that's my current code but that returns an array which means I have to deal with conversion before I can use it as a boolean. Any ideas how I can change it so that it returns an int with the value 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use a subquery:

```
def existsCheck( db, id )
    db.execute( "select 1
                 from Products
                 where promoID = ?",
                [id] ).length > 0
end
```

This returns a boolean result.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
def existsCheck( db, id )
    temp = db.execute( "select 1 where exists(
        select 1
        from Products
        where promoID = ?
    ) ", [id] ).any?
end
```

SQL query returns `1` when condition is met or empty result set if it's not. Whole function returns boolean depending on result set.

Comment: Er, how would I be able to do that in ruby? I'm using 'sqlite3'. Update: Ah, got it now that you've updated it. Thanks! :D

Comment: @user1043625 updated. Just use this query instead of yours. You've almost had the solution :-).

Comment: It still seems to return an array. if( temp != 1 ) would still always return true.

Comment: @user1043625 I'm not a Ruby programmer but, I think that you should check whether the table is empty or not. The way described here: [Check for array not empty: any?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245929/check-for-array-not-empty-any) - seems fine. Empty -> condition isn't met, otherwise it is met.

Comment: Yeah that works but then I'm actually trying to avoid doing anything extra to the returned variable.

Comment: @user1043625 I think the type of your temp object is an `enumeration` or an `array`, so you could just check if it contains any element with `temp.empty?`.