# hashes, flash and assert_not - how do I assert_not a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to finish the exercises in the Mhartl RoR tutorial.

The question asks you to complete the following integration test

```
assert_not 'flash.FILLIN'

assert_select 'div#FILLIN'
assert_select 'div.FILLIN'
```

And I have a flash that shows either

```
{:success => "success message here"}
```

or upon error,

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
```

taking the standard @user.errors.fullmessages.

My questions are:

How would I go about finding the list of @users.errors.fullmessages, and how do assert_not error?

```
assert_not 'flash.errors'
```

yields no exit:success... :(

any help appreciated, the link to the exercise is here: https://draft.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-signup_exercises

Answer (score 8):

Turns out that it is

```
assert_not flash.nil?
```

and some helpful places to look: [Check for array not empty: any?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245929/check-for-array-not-empty-any)

:)

Answer (score 4):

```
assert_not flash.empty?
```

Michael Hartl says "I prefer only to test that the flash isn’t empty" at 
http://3rd-edition.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-signup_exercises

And he writes the same test at
http://3rd-edition.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#code-successful_edit_test

Answer (score 1):

To assert that there is no `flash` message of a *particular type* set (`:error` in this example), you can do:

```
assert_predicate flash[:error], :nil?
```