# How do you check if an array element is empty or not in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, inspec

How do you check if an array element is empty or not in Ruby?

```
passwd.where { user =~ /.*/ }.uids
=> ["0",  "108",  "109",  "110",  "111",  "112",  "994",  "995",  "1001",  "1002",  "",  "65534"]
```

Comment: Any element? All elements? None?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for array not empty: any?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245929/check-for-array-not-empty-any)

Answer (score 3):

To check if the array has an empty element, one of the many ways to do it is:

```
arr.any?(&:blank?)
```

Comment: `blank?` is not the same as `empty?`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do with it, but there are quite a few ways to skin this cat. More info would help narrow it down some...

```
["0",  "108",  "109",  "110",  "111",  "112",  "994",  "995",  "1001",  "1002",  "",  "65534"].map { |v| v.empty? }
=> [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false]

["0",  "108",  "109",  "110",  "111",  "112",  "994",  "995",  "1001",  "1002",  "",  "65534"].each_with_index { |v,i| puts i if v.empty? }
10
```

Comment: i need to check the index value of array which is empty and store it in a variable like below code checking userid in linux box.                                                                       describe passwd.where { user =~ /.*/ }.uids do
    its("length") { should_not eq 0 }
  end

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [ "0",  "108",  "", [],  {},  nil, 2..1, 109, 3.2, :'' ]

arr.select { |e| e.respond_to?(:empty?) && e.empty? }
  #=> ["", [], {}, :""]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is an array of strings

```
 arr = [ "name",  "address",  "phone", "city",  "country",  "occupation"]

 if arr.empty?
   p "Array is empty"
 else
   p "Array has values inside"
```

Answer (score -1):

These test for emptiness:

```
'foo'.empty? # => false
''.empty? # => true

[1].empty? # => false
[].empty? # => true

{a:1}.empty? # => false
{}.empty? # => true
```

Testing to see if an element in an array is empty would use a similar test:

```
['foo', '', [], {}].select { |i| i.empty? }  # => ["", [], {}]
['foo', '', [], {}].reject { |i| i.empty? }  # => ["foo"]
```

or, using shorthand:

```
['foo', '', [], {}].select(&:empty?)  # => ["", [], {}]
['foo', '', [], {}].reject(&:empty?)  # => ["foo"]
```

Comment: using empty? will result in a crash if the array contains a nil

Comment: That's true, however the OP only specified a concern for "empty" nodes, not "nil" nodes.